# ISO_C_BINDING between different Fortran and C vendors

Tags: c++, c, interop, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

Is the concept of the Fortran ISO_C_BINDING module also supported by C/C++ compiler vendors? For example, the size of a C/C++ `int` can vary between the compilers from different vendors. So, with the ISO_C_BINDING module, we know that a Fortran `C_INT` type is 4 bytes; rather than merely having a *kind* of 4. But, we still don't know the size of an `int` in general in C/C++. Am I correct? Is there perhaps a standard C/C++ ISO_C_BINDING-compatible compiler switch?

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with C++?

Comment: using 'extern "C"' you can use the ISO_C_Binding to call C++ from Fortran.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the standard only demands matching types in the same toolchain. Thus you are better using the C-Compiler from the same vendor. The standard doesn't claim anything about the sizes of the C_ kinds, I think.

*Edit: Just looked it up in the standard, it is always talking about the companion C-compiler.*

Comment: This does seem very likely. After all, I wouldn't expect to link Fortran libraries from different vendors.

Comment: +1: Unfortunately, even the .mod files different fortran compilers generate aren't intercompatable; without laying out a specific binary interface for different architectures, there's no real way of ensuring intercompatability across compilers.

Comment: Indeed there is no compatibility across Fortran modules, however I quite regulary use GCC objects over the ISO-C-Binding with various other Fortran compilers from different vendors (mostly Intel), and most of the time this interplay seems to work, though there is guarantee...

Comment: The compiler vendor can only guarantee compatibility between their Fortran and C compilers.   Some other compiler could use a different interface, which could even change with versions.  That said, my experience is the same as haraldkl, that ifort and gcc mix fine.

Answer (score 2):

Most operating systems expose a C API, which obviously implies the existence of a standard C ABI on that platform. Normally, C compilers use this ABI, but there may be some peculiarities (eg, the standard calling convention for the Windows API is stdcall, which doesn't support variadic functions, thus there's a second major calling convention called cdecl).

The situation for C++ isn't as clear-cut: most operating system do not expose a C++ API (there are exceptions like BeOS/Haiku), thus compiler vendors were free to do whatever they thoght best, leading to incompatibilities between compilers from different vendors and sometimes even between different versions of the same compiler. I *think* at least GCC has stabilized their C++ ABI, but I have no idea about the general situation...

Comment: Thanks. In what sense does an operating system expose its C ABI?

Comment: @user643722: it makes no sense to have an OS API without an ABI - how would you invoke an API function if you have no concept of calling convention and argument types? Embedded code aside, a C compiler which can't interface with the OS isn't terribly useful, so it needs to support the OS ABI and almost always will use that ABI for all its code

Comment: Thanks. So the C Standard Library is seen as part of the OS? Does that mean, say, Windows doesn't expose a C API?

Comment: @user643722: the C standard library *may* be part of the OS API, or (the common case) implemented on top of it; on Windows (which has a C API), it's available as a separate library, available in different versions (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx ); the C standard places some restrictions on possible ABIs (like minimal widths of integer types), but leaves many thing up to the 'implementation', which is a generic term covering things like architecture, os and compiler